# list index out of range python1

Tags: python, python-3.x

**My Code**
I get the "list index out of range" error cant find any working solutions

```
import bs4
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def parsePrice():
    r = requests.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/%5EIXIC?p=^IXIC')
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, "xml")
    price = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'My(6px) Pos(r) smartphone_Mt(6px)'})[0].find('span')
    return price


while True:
    print('the current price:' + str(parsePrice()))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import bs4
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def parsePrice():
    r = requests.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/%5EIXIC?p=^IXIC',
                     verify=False)  # This second parameter is optional.
    soup =\
        bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text)  # Remove the second parameter here.
    price =\
        soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'My(6px) Pos(r) smartphone_Mt(6px)'})[0].\
            find('span').text  # Should retrieve only element's text.
    return price


while True:
    print('the current price:' + str(parsePrice()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Findall return an empty list if nothing is found.

```py
price = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'My(6px) Pos(r) smartphone_Mt(6px)'})[0]
```

test if price is null before indexing it.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is in the following line:

```
price = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'My(6px) Pos(r) smartphone_Mt(6px)'}[0].find('span')
```

Your list is empty and it is the cause of your problem.
Probably `{'class': 'My(6px) Pos(r) smartphone_Mt(6px)'}[0]` this portion is giving you the error.